# Gmail inaccessible abroad

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

I have a Gmail account that's not registered on my phone. I have private data in there and I don't want to keep it as my phone account.

Whenever I travel to another country, I can't access this account, because it would require me to verify the number, which is unavailable when I'm abroad and the phone gets locked up.
It doesn't offer unlocking the account using a security question or anything. It just locks up the account until I'm back home.

How can I avoid this annoyance?
Is there a way to tell Gmail in advance I'm gonna travel or add a list of safe locations in advance from time to time?

Note: 2-step verification is off.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [android.se].

Comment: How about using recovery codes instead of the phone verification?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiasts I am not sure. The question is about my Google Account, not about my phone.

Comment: @Alex, what do u mean?

Comment: You turn on 2-step verification and use one of the recovery codes instead of the code received via SMS.

Comment: Why won't you just post an answer then?